# Unable to call fabricjs mouse-events on canvas in react

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, mouseevent, fabricjs

We are unable to call fabric.js events(mouse events) in react (like canvas.on, canvas.off) but those events are working when we are using them in constructor.

```
this.canvas.on('mouse:move', function() {
                console.log('canvas event');
              });
```

we don't get console.log  when we are using in factory method.

I tried to write the  fabricjs canvas events in the  factory method but we can't get the desired output.
we were expecting the console statement on mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

`fabric.StaticCanvas` [does not support interactivity like events handling](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1#interactivity). Make sure you are using the `fabric.Canvas`, and not its static version.